# Not able to identify datatype in sqllite table

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

### I would like to migrate sql lite database to sql server. For that I did,

1. Download an ODBC driver for SQLite
2. Install the driver
3. Create a System DSN for the database
4. Create a linked server in SQL Server.

I transferred all the data except below table - EventLogTable .
When I queried using linked server.....

```
"select  * from OPENQUERY(SQLLITE,'select EventID,DateTime from EventLogTable')"
```

I got null value for DateTime column. while DataTime column has below values.

[EventLog table datetime column actual value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS3Lf.png)

### EventLogTable table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `EventLogTable` (
    `EventID`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `DateTime`  DATETIME DEFAULT (strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S','now','localtime'))

);
```

**Can you please help me how can I get these values and in which format its stored datetime value?**